# Symfony2: Create form binded to an entity with a field which is not a property

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

The following (simple) question from me:

```
  $user = new User();
  $user->setEventid(2);
  $user->setT(new \DateTime('now'));

  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $em->persist($user);
  $em->flush();

  $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
    ->add('email', 'email')
    ->add('terms', 'checkbox', array(
          'label'     => 'Read terms?',
          'required'  => true))
    ->getForm();
```

This is my code. Email is property of the user, terms not.
I want them users to save their email and check the terms-checkbox but i just need to save the email, not if they check the box - if they don't they cant submit the form.

You know what i mean? I'm shure its pretty simple to achieve this ;)

Second Question: How can i give the rendered from-tag an id-attribute for further handeling in jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a field that doesn't exist in the entity to a form, use this:

```php
->add('terms', 'checkbox', array(
    'label'         => 'Read terms?',
    'required'      => true,
    'mapped'        => false, // this works since Symfony 2.1
    'property_path' => false, // this works since Symfony 2.0
))
```

Symfony generates an ID for each form element; just open the rendered page source and see the ID of the element you need.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Regarding the ID-"problem": neighter my form nor my elements have ids - i think i can achieve ids for the elements with the 'attr' property - but how can i achieve it for the form itself??

Comment: Just add the `id` attribute to the `form` tag you output — Symfony doesn't output that tag for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a 'terms' field in your Entity, it won't be save.
For your second question, it's very simple to set an id to a form in twig, make simply :

```
{{ form_label(form.name, 'Your Name', { 'attr': {'id': 'foo'} }) }}
```

Comment: im afraid you have to talk to me like a very beginner.
if i dont have the terms field in my entity it wont be save, ok, but i dont WANT it to be saved, as explained above. the problem is, that it HAS to be property to create a form like this, because i have bound the user object to it.
(show me another way to create a form with more flexibility please)

second: exactly the same, i dont know how to create a form with self-defined form-fields, as you can see in my code above i auto-create it from the user-object.